# Request for on-hold question to be re-opened

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543394/can-i-schedule-a-workflow-in-cq5) was put on hold as being unclear what was being asked — I edited the question for clarity & flagged it for moderation attention (I don't have reopen vote privileges), but it's remained closed.

The Help section says to ask on Meta if you're unsure of the validity of a closure — From what I can see, the users who made the initial close votes don't have much activity in the tag, and with the tag being fairly low traffic, it feels like this will get to closed state before it gets many re-open votes.

Happy to try & further edit this question if it needs it, if that helps. If not, would just like to understand why it's remained closed. (I can't answer the question, but I would be interested in seeing answers to it myself too, which is why I'm interested! :) )

Comment: Good edit, but... how's that question on topic? What does it have to do with programming?

Comment: There is no need to flag for Moderator attention. This isn't something Moderators need to be involved with. By virtue of the fact you've made edits it should be placed in the "Re-open" review queue, so members of the community will see it and can vote to re-open or not.

Comment: @Yannis Since this feature isn't available OOTB, the solution is going to be code-related & involve some use of a combination of CQ5, Apache Sling or Apache Jackrabbit APIs. (Basically I'd say it's as on-topic as anything else tagged 'CQ' :)  )

Comment: @Krampus OK thanks, didn't realise that. Will know for next time!

Comment: @anotherdave Ah, that makes sense. Perhaps you could add that to the question, and make it a bit clearer that what the OP is trying to do requires a programming solution.

Comment: @Krampus True, but anotherdave's edit was a couple of days ago, /review didn't work its magic this time. I'd say flagging (or bringing it up on Meta) is the next logical step.

Comment: @Yannis: Yes, well, if the question is still off-topic or unclear and remains closed, then I'd say that /review _did_ work.

Comment: @Krampus It's pretty clear after the edit, and appears to be on-topic if you know enough about CQ5 (which I don't).

Comment: @Yannis. Cool, thanks — I've tried to hint at that in the question a bit more now with a follow up edit. Krampus, reasonably happy if the question still is deemed to be off-topic, just want to understand why & the Help centre says to raise it here, so here I am :)

Comment: I voted for reopen although it still migth need a 'what have you tried?'